# Ajax returning 400 Bad Request (xhr), admin-ajax.php returns '0'?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So I have limited experience with Ajax and I'm not entirely sure how to debug/resolve the issue. The error in question is;

> **admin-ajax.php** - 400 Bad Request (xhr).

I have checked the resource loaded and I can get a response of '0'. Looking into it I can see that a '0' response means either that the action is not set (in the ajax data) or that the action's callback function cannot be found.

Seeing as I have set an action I can only assume this is because the call back function cannot be found. But checking the code theres no typos in the callbacks?

Any help I could get would be much appreciated.

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){   
    require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() .'/inc/better-comments.php' );
    require( get_stylesheet_directory() .'/inc/ajax.php' );
});
```

**ajax.php**

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_front_load_more', 'front_load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_front_load_more', 'front_load_more');

function front_load_more() {
    
    global $post;
    $post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] );
    setup_postdata( $post );
    
    wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'better_comments' ) );
    
    die();
    
};
```

**theme.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.front-load-more', function(){
    
        var button = $(this);
 
        // decrease the current comment page value
        cpage--;
        
        $.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl, // AJAX handler, declared before
            data : {
                'action' : 'front_load_more',
                'post_id': parent_post_id, // the current post
                'cpage' : cpage, // current comment page
            },
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // preloader here
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) {
                    $('ol.comment-list').append( data );
                    button.text('More comments'); 
                     // if the last page, remove the button
                    if ( cpage == 1 )
                        button.remove();
                } else {
                    button.remove();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
        
    });
});
```

**comments.php (the trigger)**

```
<?php   
  $cpage = get_query_var('cpage') ? get_query_var('cpage') : 1;
 
  if( $cpage > 1 ) {
    echo '<a class="btn btn-block btn-soft-primary transition-3d-hover front-load-more">Load More</a>
       <script>
       var ajaxurl = \'' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '\',
            parent_post_id = ' . get_the_ID() . ',
            cpage = ' . $cpage . '
       </script>';
   }
?>
```

> **Amended** - add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_front_load_more', 'front_load_more');
>
> **Amended** - add_action('wp_ajax_front_load_more', 'front_load_more');
>
> **EDIT: 21 Jan 15:23**
> As @cabrerahector said, I had code within my ajax.php file that needed to be moved to my functions.php file. This resolved the bad request issue.

Comment: There's a difference between `front-load-more` and `front_load_more`. Stick to underscores. Also, are you sure you want to use the admin-url? Does the feature require the user to be a logged in admin?

Comment: I didn't think the css handle would matter? Is that not the case? Also no the feature has `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_front-load-more', 'front-load-more');` assigned so I thought that would negate the issue.

Comment: I notice what you mean, within the add_action handles. (Took me a sec.) I've amended this and the error persists no change.

Comment: The code you have in `ajax.php` should be in `functions.php` instead.

Comment: @cabrerahector you are right! I've amended ajax.php to functions.php and it seems to work although the response is empty. If you want to fill out an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Done! Regarding the empty response issue, you should open a new question for this. However, I noticed in your code that apparently `parent_post_id` hasn't been initialized anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code you have in `ajax.php` should be in `functions.php` instead: your `wp_ajax_*` action hooks aren't being correctly registered by WordPress, hence the `400 Bad Request` response you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks buddy, spot on!